# qt - How do I make a splitter with a set of buttons on it?

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt-jambi

Did anyone face a problem of putting buttons (or any other widgets) on the top of a splitter handle? I've tried to get the handle, set its layout and put the controls there, but I got some weird look.

My main goal is to create a selector dialog as depicted below:[image: Dialog example]

What I get:
[image]

Code:

```
QDialog dialog = new QDialog();
dialog.setLayout(new QVBoxLayout());
QSplitter splitter = new QSplitter();

splitter.setSizePolicy(new QSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.MinimumExpanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed));
splitter.addWidget(new QListWidget());
splitter.addWidget(new QTableWidget());
dialog.layout().addWidget(splitter);

QSplitterHandle h = splitter.handle(1);
h.setFixedWidth(30); // I added this line to show the splitter handle
QVBoxLayout lt = new QVBoxLayout();
lt.setSpacing(0);
lt.setMargin(0);
lt.addWidget(new QPushButton("Hello", dialog));
lt.addWidget(new QPushButton("Good bye", dialog));
h.setLayout(lt);

dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives better result:

```
// h.setFixedWidth(30);
splitter.setHandleWidth(30);
```

For better result I'd suggest to subclass QSplitterHandle and reimplement `sizeHint()`. Look through [QSplitterHandle documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qsplitterhandle.html).

You can change layout setting to get exact button positions.
For example:

```
lt.addStrecth();
```

To remove "relief"-bar you must subclass from QSplitterHandle and reimplement `paintEvent()`.

Comment: A bit better, but not suitable yet. Do you know how to avoid separating the widgets by the handle "relief"?

Comment: @AndreyAtapin It has no effect on widgets. Button positions are controlled by layout.

Comment: @AndreyAtapin I use Gentoo Linux and Qt 4.7.4.

Comment: thanks, adding stretch works, though I don't understand the magic :) I meant that "relief"-bar being pasted between buttons (see screenshot). It seems this is OS specific. Now the problem is how to remove this bar

Comment: @AndreyAtapin QSplitterHandle simply draws handle "relief" in paintEvent, in other things it's a simple QWidget.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6685/discussion-between-graphite-and-andrey-atapin)